# How can I change a part of input's name via jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have such code in my view:

```
<div class="box">
  <input type="text" name="product[size_ids][<%= size.id %>][quantity][1]" readonly class="product_quantity" placeholder="quantity from" value="1">
</div>
```

In my js I'd like to change `[1]` into `[2]` or `[3]` and so on after `[quantity]`, depending on how many additional forms I create. How can I do that?

This is what I have in my JS:

```
var i = 1

$('.add_another_price_btn').click( function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prev().clone().insertBefore($(this));
    $(this).prev().find('.remove_another_price_btn').show();
    $(this).prev().find('.product_quantity').removeAttr('readonly');
    $(this).prev().find('.product_quantity').attr('value', '');

    //This is what I tried, but it doesn't work properly. 
    $(this).prev().find('.product_quantity')
    .attr('name', function() { return $(this).attr('name') + '['+ (i++) + ']' }); 

    $('.remove_another_price_btn').click( function (ee) {
      ee.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
```

Comment: regular expression

Comment: @VijayMaheriya he did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a simple string operation with `substr` and `lastIndexOf` to replace the last part of the name.

```js
// get input and name of input
var input = $("input");
var name = input.attr("name");

// change just the last part
name = name.substr(0, name.lastIndexOf("[")) + "[2]";

// set name back to input
input.attr("name", name);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="product[size_ids][<%= size.id %>][quantity][1]" readonly class="product_quantity" placeholder="quantity from" value="1">
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Save the clone
2. Break the name using substring or split and parseInt

Like this

```
var $clone  = $(this).prev().clone(), 
    $prodQ  = $clone.find('.product_quantity'),
    name    = $prodQ.attr("name"),
    parts   = name.split("quantity]["),
    newName = parts[0]+"quantity][",
    num = parseInt(parts[1],10); // or a counter
num++;
newName += num+"]";
$prodQ.removeAttr('readonly').attr('value', '').attr('name',newName);
$clone.insertBefore($(this));
$clone.find('.remove_another_price_btn').show();
```

Comment: My IDE tells me, that smth wrong with this part: `(parseInt(parts[1],10)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Good solution.

Comment: And complete. Should be possible to just paste it in.